# Try, catch in powershell invoke-command

Tags: powershell, try-catch, invoke-command

It is not going to "catch" block as part of invoke-command for the incorrect host using powershell

```
$server= @("correcthost","Incorrecthost")
foreach($server in $server)
   {

     Try{
          Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList $server -ScriptBlock    {

             $serverk=$args[0]    
             write-host $serverk
            }
        }
    Catch
       {
        write-host "error connecting to $serverk"
       }
  }
```

I expect the catchblock getting executed as i am trying to incorrect host

but the actual output is not printing catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. First, the variable `$serverk` is out of scope in the `catch` block. It's being used only on the remote computer, so it doesn't exist - or have value - on the local system.

Debugging any Powershell script should always start with turning on the strict mode, so warnings about uninitialized variables are generated. Like so,

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 'latest'
...<code>
The variable '$serverk' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:12 char:41
+         write-host "error connecting to $serverk"
+                                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (serverk:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

The fix is easy, just refer to `$server` that's the variable used in iterating `$servers`.

The second issue is caused by `ErrorAction`, or to be specific, not declaring one. Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Invoke-Command` and process the exception in catch block like so,

```
catch{
    write-host "error connecting to $server`: $_"
}
error connecting to doesnotexist: [doesnotexist] Connecting to remote server doesnotexist failed...
```

Comment: I think you meant `-ErrorAction Stop`. It is my understanding that `continue` won't go to `catch` block.